# Unable to use anchor hash tag if using Google Analytics utm

Tags: google-analytics, html, tracking

If I want to user to go a particular section of my webpage, I will use

```
http://www.example.com/help_faq.html#contribution
```

However, sometimes, I need to track where user come from, if I use

```
http://www.example.com/help_faq.html#contribution?utm_source=jstock&utm_medium=help_menu
```

It fails to go to the particular section. Anything I can fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anchor tag should be at the end of the URL, after the query string:

`http://example.com/page.html?query=term#anchor`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the anchor with the URL and UTM parameter like this:

`http://www.example.com/help_faq.html?utm_source=jstock&utm_medium=help_menu#contribution`